# Value элемента input не возвращает введенное значение

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том чтобы по нажатию на ссылку `#link` в консоль выводилось введенное в поле `#field` значение, но получаю `''`

```js
const field = document.querySelector('#field').value;
const link = document.querySelector('#link');
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(field);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="field">
<a href="#0" id="link">Отправить</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался)

Надо `value` во время клика брать, а я в самом начале брал.

```js
const field = document.querySelector('#field');
const link = document.querySelector('#link');
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(field.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="field">
<a href="#0" id="link">Отправить</a>
```